# how to seed data in table storage?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

**How do we seed table storage tables in order to automate the deployment process?**

We've got the following resources all in the same resource group in our dev subscription:

- storage account
- events in the storage account for blob created
- config data in table storage
- function app
- logic app

In order to automate the deployment of these resources, I've downloaded the ARM template from the resource group:

[image]

We can then simply redeploy to any destination resource group:

[image]

However, this will not deploy resources like the storage tables, events, seeding data into the tables.

**How do we automatically seed table storage tables in order to automate the deployment?**

Comment: You've got a lot going on here. So you're trying to automate a deployment of a resource group that contains a storage account, function app, and logic app? What do you mean by "events in the storage account"? What is "config data" in table storage? Is that your "seed" data? What are you trying to do? Keep in mind that table storage is completely different from SQL.

Comment: in devops, you will have some process that bundles all of your resources together and then deploys everything that an application needs like services, vms, etc, now suppose one of those dependencies is a dataset within table storage. for example storing key-value pairs. how do we seed those values as part of the actual devops deploy ?

Comment: You can create a PS script locally and test it. Use this link to help you generate the script - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell then use CI/CD pipelines by including it as a step once everything is deployed after your arm template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this.

1. In your project check in your CSV file
2. In your build definition add a step to copy files - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml
3. In your release pipeline run your PS script like I mentioned in my comment above - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops

You can use something like this for your PS script to load the csv file

```
# Load the CSV
$csv = Import-CSV $PSScriptRoot'\yourSeedData.csv'

# And push it to storage
ForEach ($line in $csv)
{
    $entity = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity -ArgumentList $line.PartitionKey, $line.RowKey
    if($line.Description -ne $null) {
        $entity.Properties.Add("Property1", $line.Property1)
    }
    $entity.Properties.Add("Property2", $line.Property2)

    $result = $table.CloudTable.Execute([Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrReplace($entity))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#add-table-entities) option to seed data automatically using powershell:

```
$partitionKey1 = "partition1"
$partitionKey2 = "partition2"

# add four rows 
Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey1 `
    -rowKey ("CA") -property @{"username"="Chris";"userid"=1}

Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey2 `
    -rowKey ("NM") -property @{"username"="Jessie";"userid"=2}

Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey1 `
    -rowKey ("WA") -property @{"username"="Christine";"userid"=3}

Add-AzTableRow `
    -table $cloudTable `
    -partitionKey $partitionKey2 `
    -rowKey ("TX") -property @{"username"="Steven";"userid"=4}
```

Comment: You can include a CSV file if you're a ton of data, then use the PS to read it in and seed your azure storage table

Comment: got an exampleplease/?